# dynamic populate SELECT statement with variables

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a table with 7 columns populated from mysql... the table headers each contain a checkbox which if checked and clicked on submit will be sent to a export to csv page.

Is there a way to use the `SELECT $var1, $var2...$var7 FROM...` ? $var1 to $var7 will be used if checkbox checked and if no checkbox checked then display some message

To betted understand what i am asking i'll put some code...

HTML

```
<td class="captabel">
 <input type="checkbox" value="expid" >
</td>
<td class="captabel">
 <input type="checkbox" value="exploc" >            
</td>
etc
```

php

```
if(isset($_POST['expid'])){
$expid="id";
}
else{
$expid="";
}
if(isset($_POST['exploc'])){
$exploc="locatie";
}
else{
$exploc="";
}
etc
```

and at some point comes the `SELECT * FROM table...` <-- this is what i want to replace with `SELECT $expid, $exploc ... FROM table...`
i have tried various ways and none worked.
Thanks.

Comment: *"I have tried various ways and none worked*" - Well you're going to have to include those. We're not here to write code for you, we're here to help you correct the code you've already written :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Based on Dipanwita Kundu answer i used

```
if(!empty($columns)){
    $sql = 'SELECT '. implode(', ', $columns). ' FROM raport' ;
}
```

and works like a charm.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `name` attribute on your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" value="123" name="expid" />
```

Comment: Thank you for that... how that i couldn't see?!?

Answer (score 1):

1. Modify your input type `<input type="checkbox" name="exploc" value="exploc">`
2. In your php script check :

   ```
   $selectStr= "";
   if(!empty($_POST['expid'])) {
     $selectStr="id";
   }
   else{
    $selectStr="";
   }
   if(!empty($_POST['exploc'])) {
     $selectStr= !empty($selectStr) ? ", locatie" : "locatie";
   }
   else{
    $selectStr="";
   }
   ```

so your query will be

```
    if(!empty($selectStr)) {
      $qry = "SELECT $selectStr FROM table...";
     }
```

Instead of setting different name you can set array type name in `<input type="checkbox" value="exploc" name="exploc[]">`

Comment: Thank you for the response. What will you do if there are like 17 checkboxes? how will the if statements look like?